# Visual Studio 2010 - Add New Connection (SQL) as a different Windows Authenticated user

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

Here is my situation.

Domain Name: myDomain
user:   bob

I want to create a connection to a SQL server in myDomain from VS Studio 2010 as a different Windows user (not SQL Authentication)

My SQL admins will only build a user id myDomain\AppUser

Is there a way to specify a different user/pwd as a Windows authenticated ?

TIA.

Ralph

Comment: What does c# have to do with it?  Are you connecting within a program?

Comment: I fixed the tag. c# is not in play. Just the connection wizard from Visual Studio. Though my WinForm App is c# in case it matters to someone.

Comment: Why are you avoiding using SQL Auth?

Answer (score 1):

You can connect with a distinct domain user from VS if you open the Visual Studio as that user using "run as".
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The shellrunas tool from sysinternals (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc300361) works very well for this purpose.  You don't even need to be in the same domain as the target server.  Just pass in the credentials (i.e. username and password) and you should be good to go.